# Compare two text list , check for duplicate and mark it the end of line

Tags: python, duplicates, text-files

I am trying to do a 3 part program. I have two text file , Text File A and Text File B

Text File A has to compare the data with Text File B. If there  is a duplicate, it will email it.
If there is no duplicate, it will write the data to text file B.

The issue I am having is that, the duplication always starts from the start of text file. I am trying to find the code, start it from last line it checked.

This is my duplication code.

```
f1 = open("/path/to/file1", "r") 
f2 = open("/path/to/file2", "r") 

txtfileA = f1.read()
txtfileB = f2.read()

txtfileA_words = txtfileA.split()
txtfileB_words = txtfileB.split()

result = set(textfileA_words).difference(set(txtfileB_words))

print result
```

Is there better set of codes, am I doing something wrong?

Any advice would be nice.

Comment: What constitutes a duplicate?  A line?  A character?  A word?

Comment: @jgritty -- It looks like whitespace separated "words" from the code snippet.

Comment: If you're looking for duplicates, why are you using `set.difference`?  Shouldn't you be using `set.intersection`?

Comment: In each line , you will find 8 characters long from 0-9,a-z. It will be mix of those.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the intersection function, not difference.  Also, you had a typo in the variable name.

```
f1 = open("/path/to/file1", "r") 
f2 = open("/path/to/file2", "r") 

txtfileA = f1.read()
txtfileB = f2.read()

txtfileA_words = txtfileA.split()
txtfileB_words = txtfileB.split()

# remove the extra e in textfileA_words and use intersection
result = set(txtfileA_words).intersection(set(txtfileB_words))

print result
```

Comment: What is the difference between Intersection vs Difference

Comment: difference: Return a new set with elements in the set that are not in the others.

Comment: intersection: Return a new set with elements common to the set and all others.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
with open('path/to/file1', 'r') as f1, open('path/to/file2', 'r') as f2:
    result = set(f1.read().split()).intersection(set(f2.read().split())
```

Comment: What is the difference between with open and regular open

Comment: `with open` will automatically close the file when it's done.